# Passing Git credentials to Ansible throwing an error

Tags: ansible, yaml, ansible-2.x

I am following this page, [Clone a private git repository with Ansible (using password prompt)](https://www.claudiokuenzler.com/blog/604/clone-a-private-git-repository-with-ansible-password-prompt#.WVnwKYSGOpo) to solve my requirement. Re-used the same template in my playbook `main.yml` whose contents are as

```
---
- name: move CentOS repo definitions outside temp
  copy:
    src: "{{ item }}"
    dest: /etc/yum.repos.d/
    owner: "root"
    mode: 0600
  with_fileglob:
    - /etc/yum.repos.d/temp/*
  become: true

- name: passing git credentials for cloning the repos
  vars_prompt:
    - name: "githubuser"
      prompt: "Enter your github username"
      private: no
    - name: "githubpassword"
      prompt: "Enter your github password"
      private: yes
```

and some more below. Am facing an error

```
The error appears to have been in '/tmp/.../tasks/main.yml': line 12, column 3, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:


- name: passing git credentials for cloning the repos
  ^ here


The error appears to have been in '/tmp/.../tasks/main.yml': line 12, column 3, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:


- name: passing git credentials for cloning the repos
  ^ here
```

I validated the `yml` using the syntax check option available

```
ansible-playbook main.yml --syntax-check
```

and also on the [YAML lint](http://www.yamllint.com/), but can't seem to find the reason why the error is seen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `vars_prompt` at task level, only at playbook level.

If your `main.yml` is a part of role, you should move prompt block to upper level playbook that includes your role.

Comment: Great observation! Am checking if I can possibly move it to the upper level.  Also is there an alternate way to achieve this other than by using `vars_prompt`?

Comment: Ansible is an **automation tool** at the first place. So avoid as much interactive activity as possible, use extra-vars, environment variables to pass additional data into your playbooks.

Comment: Thanks for the lead into this. Removed the approach altogether, decided to use an encrypted var file containing the credentials. Thanks